# java8 new feature with spring error

Tags: spring, java-8

`Map<String, User> map = users.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getUsername, e -> e));`
 
the code run normally,but long time no operations then route to this code will make the followed error.

please help me!!!

```
2016-04-24 17:51:56.262 ERROR 8343 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springsource.loaded.support.Java8.callLambdaMetaFactory(Java8.java:153)
    at org.springsource.loaded.support.Java8.emulateInvokeDynamic(Java8.java:88)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.idyrun(TypeRegistry.java:1787)
    at crazy.action.ExcelAction.createEntryExcel(ExcelAction.java:86)
    at crazy.action.ExcelAction.get(ExcelAction.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User::getUsername
```

will call user.getUsername(). It looks like you have an entry in your map where the value (the user) is null, this leads to the shown exception.

Comment: I can make sure the user is not null.  In the web system, once fetch the url,the method is normal,bug long time no operations the method would throw the exception.